# View my 404 page on my localhost, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localhost, http-status-code-404

So I've been working on my 404 page, because 404s are frustrating enough without poor formatting and bland design, but whenever I make a change, I don't know how to view it on my localhost. If I go to a page that doesn't exits, (`localhost:3000/foobar`), it simply says there is no route for it. Same thing happens if I go directly to `localhost:3000/public/404.html`. Every time I want to view it, I have to push it to heroku, which is frustrating and breaks my standard for coding.

Is there any way to render my 404 page on my localhost?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

leave out the public part

```
localhost:3000/404.html
```